# nodejs config on subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sub-domain and I publish my `server.js` on this directory. everything work fine. but I want to running my `server.js` inside a directory(because I want to run my `react.js` project on sub directory). for example:

web.example.com/sr

`web` is my subdomain and `sr` is my directory.

but my routes not worked at all:

```
web.example.com/sr/user/1
```

I got this error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /sr/user/1</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should I make any changes or is there any config to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do deployment-level configs to serve your react app to the subdir `/sr`. Every call to `your.domain.com/sr/*` will end up in your server and pass `/sr/*` to it (and not simply `/*`.

You'll have to code your server to serve your React app. If you bundle your react app to `index.html` and `bundle.js`, you'll have to write something like this (if you're using express, which you probably do):

```
app.get(/\/sr\/\.js/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/bundle.js`));
app.get(/\/sr\/*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`));
```

If you're using react-router, you'll have to set it up too so as to take into account the leading `/sr` in your URL.